# Java Exceptions Prevent Closing The Program (when clicking X button)

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, joptionpane, throw

I've built a little random number generator using JOptionPane. The exceptions that I've written prevent the user from quitting the program when clicking the X button. I've done lots of research and tried several things but nothing seems to work.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;

public class Generate {
    private int number;
    private int min;
    private int max;
    private int repeat;
    Random no = new Random();
    int x = 1;

    void generateNumber() {
        do {
            try {
                String from = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Welcome to Random Number Generator!\n\nPlease insert your number range.\n\nFrom:", "Random Number Generator", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, "Enter Number");
                min = Integer.parseInt(from);

                String to = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "To:", "Random Number Generator", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, "Enter Number");
                max = Integer.parseInt(to);
                System.out.println();

                String count = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many numbers would you like?", "Random Number Generator", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, "Enter Number");
                repeat = Integer.parseInt(count);
                System.out.println();

                for (int counter = 1; counter <= repeat; counter++) {
                    number = no.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Random number #" + counter + ": " + number, "Random Number Generator", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
               x = 2;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INPUT ERROR: please insert a number", "Random Number Generator", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INPUT ERROR: the second number needs to be higher than the first", "Random Number Generator", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            } while(x == 1);
        }
}
```

Main:

```
  class RandomNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generate obj = new Generate();
        obj.generateNumber();
    }
}
```

[This is what happens when I try to close the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InYsv.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't test the `from` value after `showInputDialog()` invocations.

For example here :

```
String from = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,...
```

After this call, You chain directly with

```
min = Integer.parseInt(from);
```

whatever the value of `from`.
If `from` is `null` you finish in this `catch` as `null` is not a number :

```
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "INPUT ERROR: please insert a number", "Random Number Generator",
        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

And x has still `1` as value. So the loop condition is still `true`.

To solve your problem, you just to test the value returned by `showMessageDialog()` and if the value is `null`, let the user exits from the method.

Add this code at each time you retrieve a user input and that you want to enable the user to exit :

```
if (from == null) {
    return;
}
```